# Extend the same class with 2 modules? Magento module conflict?

Tags: magento, module, e-commerce, conflict

Im trying to make a module that changes the title of a page, my module works fine until I enable another module called

Yoast_CanonicalUrl.

The Yoast module does not touch any of the title methods but does extend the same class as my module: Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head{}

I have tried extending the yoast class if it exists but my module ceases to function once the yoast module is enabled.

I have looked though yoasts code to see if his methods confict with mine and they dont.

Just seems as soon as Yoast is loaded my code just isnt loaded anymore :(

Here is my Head.php:

```
<?php

if (!(string)Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Yoast_CanonicalUrl')->active == 'true')
{
  class Yoast_CanonicalUrl_Block_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head{}
}
class Company_MetaKeyManager_Block_Head extends Yoast_CanonicalUrl_Block_Head
{
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->_data['title'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_prefix') . ' ' . $title
            . ' ' . Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_suffix');
        return $this;
    }
    public function getTitle()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['title'])) {
            $this->_data['title'] = $this->getDefaultTitle();
        }
        return htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(trim($this->_data['title']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    }
    public function getDefaultTitle()
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

Here is my Config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_MetaKeyManager>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_MetaKeyManager>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <MetaKeyManager>
                <class>Company_MetaKeyManager_Block</class>
            </MetaKeyManager>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_head>Company_MetaKeyManager_Block_Head</html_head>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <MetaKeyManager>
                <class>Company_MetaKeyManager_Helper</class>
            </MetaKeyManager>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to why this happens?

Comment: This is an old conflict. What version of Magento are you using? Magento has canonical URLs oob since 1.4.

Comment: My Magento is version: 1.6.2.0 CE My version already has canonical urls?

Comment: It does on product and category pages. Turn on/off in the admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eeek - do not try and conditionally declare a class name/extension.

When working with potential class loading and priority conflicts, first remember the PHP autoloader priority (include_path)

It tries in this order:

```
./app/code/local
./app/code/community
./app/code/core
```

So anything defined in local will override community, regardless of any internal Magento rewrites.

With your extension, either change the Yoast extension to extend yours. Or, remove the rewrite from the Yoast extension config.xml, and have your extension extend the Yoast one.

And if you happen to want to override the same function, be sure to just

```
return parent::myfunction()
```

At the end of your function and then it will carry out the extended class' function.

Simples.

Answer (score 1):

this is a race condition, whoever gets to extend the class first. So it seems that Yoast is first so make Yoast to extend your class that extends the same class to solve this

Comment: Is there a reason that extending Yoasts class doesn't work? The solution can't be to modify other modules to get mine working =/

Comment: well you only get one time to extend a class in php so try this out if conflicts happen you can always rewrite yoast class in config already instead of page_block_html_head

Comment: Yeah, extend the Yoast class and rewrite it by your module